# Sequenctiel numbers with the next values being smaller by x the nthe previous in python

Tags: python, sequence

i'm looking for a way to create a sequence of number starting at a with n number of values.
The trick is that i want a to be say 75 then b to be 5% of a, and c 5% of b and so on.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def generate_numbers(a, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a = 0.05 * a

lst = list(generate_numbers(a, n))
```

All you need to do is choose `a` and `n`. Here are a few examples:

```
>>> list(generate_numbers(107, 3))
[107, 5.3500000000000005, 0.2675]
>>> list(generate_numbers(75, 4))
[75, 3.75, 0.1875, 0.009375000000000001]
```